# Rest Endpoint Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring-boot

Below is my rest endpoint. I used Long for data type for *userId*, Its working fine when calling the endpoint via postmen like below and I am able to handle exceptions explicitly.

localhost:8080/order-service/save-order/1

but when I am calling like this with a string type parameter,

localhost:8080/order-service/save-order/abc

the spring boot implicitly handles the exception and give 400 bad request.

what I want is to throw a custom error message like "please send proper userId" when the variable type of parameter not equal to long.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/save-order/{userId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> addOrder(@Valid @RequestBody 
         OrderDTO orderDto, @Valid @PathVariable(name = "userId") Long userId) throws BatchException, UserExceptions, BatchIdException, InvalidDateFormatException, DeliveryIdException,BatchMerchantException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ExceptionResponse("Order Saved", 201, orderServiceImpl.saveOrder(orderDto, userId)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own custom validator, see here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Return true if the input fits and false if not, you can also define the message there you want to show the user if he enters a wrong input.

Comment: In this case, this is an illegal argument exception, right? but spring boot automatically throwing bad requests. Custom validator if application throw exception we can handle that exception but in this case, we have to override the spring boot default exception.

Comment: No, it would be an org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException with a 400 status code, if you want to handle it differently you can also catch that Exception and build the responseEntity with the code you want and return it. You can also use a GlobalExceptionHandler.

Comment: but that guy is telling in console no exception throwing but in response, 400 bad requests are coming so that exception is handled by spring boot right? then how can we handle that?

Comment: yes, you are correct, no exceptions messages throwing on the console but response coming as 400.

Comment: But the 400 is the correct status code for such cases, maybe 422 Unprocessable Entity if you want to be very detailed, if you use the custom validator you can set the message by yourself that you want to show to the user together with the 4xx status code, am I missing something?

Comment: Spring boot has a default exception handler, why you dont see the exception is that it gets thrown by jackson and then caught by spring boot and handled and converted into a response with status 400.

Usually if you want to handle this is that you create your own `@ControllerAdvice`.

https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api